# Still asked for credit card during testing - Test purchase of IAP in Android app through Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I setup a test account as per the description at http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

When trying to purchase a consumable, it recognizes the current account as a test account ("This is a test order, you will not be charged."), however it still asks for a real credit card and/or code. Why is this? Can I use a test card or something?

I found a link. http://suda.pl/the-hell-of-testing-google-play-in-app-billing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, it seems that the only way to go with Google Play IAP testing is to use actual payment methods - the system claims not to actually charge us and that might just be true. I did find some people mentioning that charges still were going through to them, and they had to deal with reclaims. That information seemed to be pretty old and may not be accurate as of now - August 2015. So hopefully no charges will go through.

Still adding real credit cards and/or Google Play credits for testing purposes just does not make sense.

Comment: I got charged. Right now I'm not sure how we can test IAP on Android..